# "vlookup" with two conditions without a loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

List item

I have a very long df with 14 culumns and I would like to add to a new column the values of an other df taking in account 2 conditions. However, both df do not have the same length.
I know this is not the write way but I would like something like this:
if df1[A] == df2[A] and df1[B] == df2[B], df2[C]. I would prefere not using a for loop for iterating the list.

I give an example of what I expect:

df1

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 1 | b |
| 2 | 1 | c |
| 3 | 2 | a |
| 4 | 2 | b |
| 5 | 2 | c |

df2

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | S |
| 1 | 1 | b | E |
| 2 | 1 | c | E |

output:

df3

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | S |
| 1 | 1 | b | E |
| 2 | 1 | c | E |
| 3 | 2 | a | nan |
| 4 | 2 | b | nan |
| 5 | 2 | c | nan |

then I want to export df3 and then reimport for adding new values to C in df3 from df4:

df4

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | a | S |
| 1 | 2 | b | E |
| 2 | 2 | c | S |

update df3

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | S |
| 1 | 1 | b | E |
| 2 | 1 | c | E |
| 3 | 2 | a | S |
| 4 | 2 | b | E |
| 5 | 2 | c | S |

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.9.16

```
import pandas as pd

# Build example data frames
data1 = {
    'key': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1).set_index('key')
print(df1)

data2 = {
    'key': [0, 1, 2],
    'A': [1, 1, 1],
    'B': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'C': ['S', 'E', 'E'],
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2).set_index('key')
print(df2)

# Do the "vlookup" on the index
df3 = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='l', rsuffix='r')  # The suffices are required because both your dataframes share the same column names.
print(df3)

df3['A'] = df3.apply(lambda row: row.Al if row.Al else row.Ar, axis=1)
df3['B'] = df3.apply(lambda row: row.Bl if row.Bl else row.Br, axis=1)
print(df3)

df3 = df3.drop(columns=['Al', 'Ar', 'Bl', 'Br'])
print(df3)
```

Results:

```
     A  B
key      
0    1  a
1    1  b
2    1  c
3    2  a
4    2  b
5    2  c
     A  B  C
key         
0    1  a  S
1    1  b  E
2    1  c  E
     Al Bl   Ar   Br    C
key                      
0     1  a  1.0    a    S
1     1  b  1.0    b    E
2     1  c  1.0    c    E
3     2  a  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     2  b  NaN  NaN  NaN
5     2  c  NaN  NaN  NaN
     Al Bl   Ar   Br    C  A  B
key                            
0     1  a  1.0    a    S  1  a
1     1  b  1.0    b    E  1  b
2     1  c  1.0    c    E  1  c
3     2  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  a
4     2  b  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  b
5     2  c  NaN  NaN  NaN  2  c
       C  A  B
key           
0      S  1  a
1      E  1  b
2      E  1  c
3    NaN  2  a
4    NaN  2  b
5    NaN  2  c
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello robot, the code is reproducible and therefore able to be confirmed as correct.